# Matplotlib Contour Graphs

Tags: python, arrays, linspace

I am a student using matplotlib for research, and I am trying to plot some data points for two variables alongside the ratio (z) of x/y or the previous two variables.

I am a bit new to this, but where would I insert my points?

Right now I have inserted my x and y values for 3 points in the two lines of code shown below but I get an error whenever I list more than 3 values which makes me think this is for the array and is not where I am supposed to insert my points for x and y. Thank you for the help.

```
xlist = np.linspace( 570, 100, 10, 100)
ylist = np.linspace( 800, 1000, 1000, 100)
```

Comment: the values that you enter are not points on the line, but in fact the `start`, `stop` and `interval`....

Answer (score 0):

The actual function does this "Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval". in particular, the first 2 parameters are the `start` and the `stop` and the third parameter is `the number of samples to generate`.

So the linespace function looks like this:

```py
def linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None,
             axis=0):
    """
    Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.

    Returns `num` evenly spaced samples, calculated over the
    interval [`start`, `stop`].

    The endpoint of the interval can optionally be excluded.

    .. versionchanged:: 1.16.0
        Non-scalar `start` and `stop` are now supported.

    .. versionchanged:: 1.20.0
        Values are rounded towards ``-inf`` instead of ``0`` when an
        integer ``dtype`` is specified. The old behavior can
        still be obtained with ``np.linspace(start, stop, num).astype(int)``

    Parameters
    ----------
    start : array_like
        The starting value of the sequence.
    stop : array_like
        The end value of the sequence, unless `endpoint` is set to False.
        In that case, the sequence consists of all but the last of ``num + 1``
        evenly spaced samples, so that `stop` is excluded.  Note that the step
        size changes when `endpoint` is False.
    num : int, optional
        Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must be non-negative.
    endpoint : bool, optional
        If True, `stop` is the last sample. Otherwise, it is not included.
        Default is True.
    retstep : bool, optional
        If True, return (`samples`, `step`), where `step` is the spacing
        between samples.
    dtype : dtype, optional
        The type of the output array.  If `dtype` is not given, the data type
        is inferred from `start` and `stop`. The inferred dtype will never be
        an integer; `float` is chosen even if the arguments would produce an
        array of integers.
```

So you can see that the inputs are the arguments and the description of what they do.

I got this from the `linspace` definition...